# rails RESTful routing with Devise not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

Using Devise 3.0 and Rails 4.0

I can't seem to get my normal restful routes working.

When I visit **URL/products/** or **URL/products/3460** (to view the "show" action of a specific product) I'm given the following error respectively:

```
Missing Template

Missing template products/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.
```

**Products_controller.rb**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

def index
  @products = Product.all
end

def show 
 @product = Product.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @product }
end

end
```

I also have index.html.erb and show.html.erb views files in **app/views/product**

**rake routes** output:

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)     devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)     devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)    devise/sessions#destroy
            products GET    /products(.:format)          products#index
                     POST   /products(.:format)          products#create
         new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)      products#new
        edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format) products#edit
             product GET    /products/:id(.:format)      products#show
                     PATCH  /products/:id(.:format)      products#update
                     PUT    /products/:id(.:format)      products#update
                     DELETE /products/:id(.:format)      products#destroy
                root GET    /                            application#index
                     GET    /products(.:format)          products#index
               login GET    /login(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
              logout DELETE /logout(.:format)            devise/sessions#destroy
```

Anyone see anything obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`show.html.erb` view file must be present in `app/views/products` directory.

**Note** `products`**(plural)** and not `product`(singular).